# How can I add special characters to android:digits on xamarin.android?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, special-characters

I'm trying to add a filter to an EditText

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="Full Name"
    android:singleLine="true" android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÇÁÀÃÂÉÈÊÍÌÎÓÒÕÔÚÙÛabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzçáàãâéèêíìîóòõôúùû " android:inputType="textFilter"/>
```

But when I added this characters: ÇÁÀÃÂÉÈÊÍÌÎÓÒÕÔÚÙÛçáàãâéèêíìîóòõôúùû
all my Resource ID's that stays below this EditText stopped from working

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably another approach would be create the android digits rule in code as below

```
etFullName.KeyListenerAndroid.Text.Method.DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÇÁÀÃÂÉÈÊÍÌÎÓÒÕÔÚÙÛabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzçáàãâéèêíìîóòõôúùû");
```